# paypal error messages not in correct language

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox

We do express checkout(on sandbox) and we set "zh_CN" in the create recurring payments profile

```
    CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType reqType = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();
    reqType.setVersion(VERSION);
    reqType.setErrorLanguage(getLangCode());
```

We also happen to set it in the request paypal token api as well in two places(which works since the paypal site shows up in chinese)...

```
    setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setReturnURL(url);
    setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setCancelURL(url2);
    setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setPaymentDetails(paymentDetailsList);
            //This is the first place which works!!!! as the paypal GUI shows up in chinese...
    setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setLocaleCode(getLangCode());
    setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails.setBuyerEmail(user.getEmail());

    SetExpressCheckoutRequestType setExpressCheckoutRequest = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType(setExpressCheckoutRequestDetails);
    setExpressCheckoutRequest.setVersion(VERSION);  
            //This is the second location which probably doesn't work though this request has never failed :( and I don't know how to force a failure :( as putting amount 105.37 on negative testing did not work
    setExpressCheckoutRequest.setErrorLanguage(getLangCode());
```

We then comment out the startdate of the billing period to cause a failure since negative testing is not working (see post [how to simulate payment denial in paypal sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818171/how-to-simulate-payment-denial-in-paypal-sandbox) ).  This causes a failure but the errors that come back are in English not chinese saying "Start Date is required" and long message "Subscription start date is required" error code 11549.

Why is this not working?  (We just simply display the paypal errors because it seems like too many to translate all the time but it's not in the correct language).

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the API responses, right? Those are (US) English only.
It's good practice to map PayPal API error responses to an appropriate customer-facing message on your end (which can of course be in any language you'd like).

I wouldn't recommend exposing PayPal API error responses directly to a customer.

Comment: then what is the setErrorLanguage function for?